# JPA eclipselink persist entity that has no primary key but two foreign keys

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1, java-ee-8

I am very new to java EE and self-learning it, so please be patient with me. So far I have 3 simple tables in my database:

| Sales | Products |
| --- | --- |
| Sale_id | Product_id |

| Sale_details |
| --- |
| Saleid_fk |
| Productid_fk (fk) |
| Quantity_sold |

How do I persist a new sale_details without creating a sale_details entity. Because Java wont let me name sale_details as @Entity without a primary key.
this current code gives me an error stating i need to declare a primary key. I tried using Idclass based on the answers on stackoverflow but it doesn't do anything.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sale_details")
@IdClass(value = SaleDetails.class)
public class SaleDetails implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "saleid_fk")
    private int saleid_fk;

    @Column(name = "productid_fk")
    private String productid_fk;

    @Column(name = "quantity_sold")
    private int quantity_sold;
```

what am I missing here?
[image: sale_details table:]

Comment: Can you share the exact table definitions? In particular: can you verify that the pair `(Sale_id, Product_id)` on table `sale_details` is guarded by an `UNIQUE` constraint? --- A comment on the code: The column names in  class `SaleDetails` do not match the column names in table `sale_details`.

Comment: @Turing85 I posted the table definition, i manually types the table diagrams, so thats why they're not the same, my apologies for the confusion. Sale_id and Product_id are not unique, because there could be multiple sale_details for one sane_id and/or multiple sale_details for one product.

Comment: In this case, the pair `(saleid_fk, quantity_sold)` is unique and can be used for a JPA `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`. See [this article at Baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys) for details.

Comment: Remark: I question the decision of making the pair `(saleid_fk, quantity_sold)` as unique. What if tow separate items are sold in the same sale in the same quantity? The current structure would not allow this scenario.

Comment: @Turing85 Would it not? They would have the same sale_id and quantity, but different Product_ids.  I tried the Idclass, and got this error:       Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [com.owl.server.objects.SaleDetails] and those of the entity bean class [class com.owl.server.objects.SaleDetails] must correspond and their types must be the same.

Comment: `SaleDetails` should not be the primary key class, but the user of the primary key class. For a more precise anlysis, We would have to see the code. This, however, is a different question and [we should limit ourselfs to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @Turing85 okay, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set a primary id as autoincrement and not use it.